# Fixed background image PhoneGap/Steroids?

Tags: ios, css, cordova, background, webview

This is a weird scenario, because normally I'd just use CSS.  I'm developing an iOS app with [steroids](/questions/tagged/steroids) (similar to PhoneGap).  The web view does not support the CSS fixed background.

Is there a solution to this?  I haven't been able to find one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just tried a 'hack' and it worked.  Here's the solution in case anyone else has this problem:

HTML:

```
<img class="background" src="img/background.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
.background {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have found that for large pages this approach leads to performance issues, see section 5 of the following article: http://publish.illinois.edu/weiyang-david/2013/06/05/phonegap-app-problemssuggestions/